# How do I transform lambda's outcomes into a list?

Tags: python

I recently got an assignment which involves probability with dice, now, I almost finished it, but I can't find out how I transform the outcome of a lambda, like this one; `lambda x:1/6` into a list.

Im using random.choices to calculate the outcome of my dice. For random.choices, I need a list of sides for my dice like `[1,2,3,4]` and a list of probabilities, like `[1/6,1/5,1/6,1/5 etc]` and a k value, which, in my code, decides the number of dice thrown.

So I get a list of 'inputs' like so;

```
S1 = 6, {1,2,3,4}, lambda x:1/6
```

I've figured out how to use the first 2 values, but I have no idea how to transform `lambda x:1/6` into `[1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6]`

working with python 3.7

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: 1/6, range(6)))` ?

Comment: or you can use list comprehension: `[1/6 for i in range(6)]`

Comment: @DanielMesejo your dice starts at  `0`? ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands actually as the lambda does not uses x, it does not matter. If what he wants is a list of 6 1/6

Comment: @DanielMesejo one assumes they also want the dice, if the just want the probabilities, then they would just do `[1/6] * 6`